# Can't assign empty initializer to vector of unique_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr, unordered-map

I have the following code:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<class EventTrigger>>> triggers;

if (triggers.end() == triggers.find(eventName)) {
   triggers[eventName] = {};
}
```

That results in an error about using a deleted constructor of unique_ptr. If, on the other hand, I do this, everything compiles fine:

```
if (triggers.end() == triggers.find(eventName)) {
   triggers[eventName] = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<class EventTrigger>>();
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I thought the empty initializer list would have resulted in an empty vector being assigned to `triggers[eventName]`.

Comment: By the way, if your goal is to add the key with the default value, you can just write `triggers[eventName];` . You don't need to check with `find` first - `operator[]` does both the lookup and "insert with default if not present" parts.

Comment: Put a comment after it, though, otherwise _someone_ will think it was an accident.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`triggers[eventName] = {}` resolves to `vector<T>::operator=(std::initializer_list<T>)`. This operator requires copying elements from the initializer list to the vector.

`triggers[eventName] = std::vector<...>()` resolves to `vector<T>::operator=(vector<T>&&)` - the move assignment operator. This doesn't require copying any elements, just transferring ownership of existing storage.